# dojo "Object does not support this action " in IE

Tags: dojo, grid

I faced a strange problem in IE with Dojo EnhancedGrid.

The data for the grid I get from server with AJAX, then in load() method i'm trying to go through all the elements in the grid. And here things go mad in IE. Here is the method that tries to get elements :

```
                var grid = dijit.byId(prefix + "mySuperGrid");

                for (var i = 0 , l = grid.getTotalRowCount(); i < l; i++) {
                                item = grid.getItem(i);
                }
```

In the first iteration I get

> object does not support this action

In FireFox the same code works perfectly.

Comment: May I ask why you are iterating over all the items after the grid is loaded? The reason I ask is because it is expensive to do that. Typically a format function or an onItem() on the datastore is the place where custom processing for an item is done

Comment: THe reason why I'm going through all the elements is that I have an item that I need to light up in the table and I'm trying to find it. The item obtained before the grid is loaded so after that I need to iterate over all the items in the grid and find the row that should be selected.

Answer (score 2):

Ok I found the bad guy. The thing was that IE needs `var` keyword before variable name when firefox does not. So the code should be :

```
            var grid = dijit.byId(prefix + "mySuperGrid");

            for (var i = 0 , l = grid.getTotalRowCount(); i < l; i++) {
                           var item = grid.getItem(i);
            }
```